# If $ 5x+12y=60$ , what is the minimum of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I know this can be easily done by solving for $y$ and substituting, so that you only have to find the minimum value of the parabola $\large x^2 + \left ( \frac {60-5x}{12} \right)^2$ using standard techniques, but is there a less messy way to do this using inequalities? I tried various things such as $AM-GM$, but I don't get anywhere. One thing which I did notice about the restriction is that it is of the form $ax+by=ab$, but I don't know how to make any use of that. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: draw the graphs.

Comment: Of what? I have $5x+12y$ equal to $60$, but I dont have $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ equal to anything, and I don't think you mean making this equal to $z$.

Comment: Why is your title different from your actual question?

Comment: @sidth My title is my question, I am just specifying that I need a different way of answering that question

Comment: @Ovi To expand on Chris Eagle's hint, what does $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ mean geometrically?

Comment: The fact that $ax+by=ab$ is not really relevant to the question, though it could help in terms of making algebraic manipulations easier.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ok thank you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Note that
$$(5x+12y)^2+(12x-5y)^2=(13^2)(x^2+y^2).$$
Since $5x+12y$ is given, we minimize $x^2+y^2$ by minimizing $(12x-5y)^2$. The minimum value of this is $0$. It follows that the minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is $\dfrac{60}{13}$.

Comment: How did you think of this?

Comment: To come out with this you should read the proof of Cauchy's inequality. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: There are many proofs, but there is one that is a one-line proof. based on one identity of which this is a particular case.

Comment: @Ovi: The cancelling middle terms idea comes up often.

Comment: +1 Classy! Nice to see these kind of ideas almost like from the Book.

Comment: @CalvinLin: For general mathematical reasons, I prefer your geometric approach.

Comment: @andrenicolas sorry for the stupid question but how do you know the minimum of $(12x-5y)^2$ is $0$?

Comment: A square is never $\le 0$. So the min is $\ge 0$. But $(12x-5y)^2=0$ when $12x=5y$, so the min is $0$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Consider the graph of the line $5x+12y = 60$.

**Hint:** The minimum value occurs when the circle with origin as center, is tangential to the above line.

**Hint:** Find the point of tangency. Use the fact that a tangent is perpendicular to the radius.

---

Apply (weighted) QM-AM, we have

$\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{169}} = \sqrt{\frac{25 \times \frac{x^2}{25} + 144 \times \frac{y^2}{144}}{169}} \geq \frac{ 25 \times \frac{x}{5} + 144 \times \frac{y}{12} } { 169 } = \frac{ 5x+12y}{169} = \frac{60}{169}$.

SO $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \geq \frac{60}{13} $

Comment: Oh ok thanks, this is a good way but is there a way to do this by manipulating inequalities?

Comment: @Ovi Added a way to do it by QM-AM. But Andre's solution is great.

Comment: And by the way how do you conclude that the minimum value occurs when the graphs are tangent?

Comment: @Ovi $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ represents a circle of radius $r$. As we increase $r$ the family of circles slowly expands, till it's tangential to the line. At this point, the minimum occurs.

Comment: That doesn't make sense; $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ can be thought of as the distance from the origin to a point of intersection between the line and a circle. So how are you sure that this distance is minimized when the circle is tangent?

Comment: The distance of the point $(X,Y)$ to the origin is given by $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$. All of the points having the same value of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ form a circle.... Another approach is to say that 1. clearly the circle has to intersect the line, to get a solution. 2. If the circle intersects the line at 2 distinct points, then any point on the line segment will lead to a smaller value. Hence, there is only 1 point of intersection, so tangential.

Comment: Oh ok thank you the more detailed explanation made sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the minimum distance from point $(0,0)$ to the mentioned straightline finding the perpendicular straightline which passes through $(0,0)$ and then its intersection.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a graph of $5x+12y=60$. $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is minimum when it is the shortest distance from origin to $5x+12y=60$. The distance can be found using the area of the triangle and length of the hypotenuse. Area = $30$, hypotenuse = $13$. Therefore, distance = $\dfrac{60}{13}$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\langle z,v\rangle = 60$ for $z:=(x,y)$ and $v=(5,12)$. We want to minimize $|z|$, or what is the same $|z|^2=\langle z,z\rangle$. Now, from Cauchy's inequality $|\langle z,v\rangle|\leq |z||v|$. From there you get the bound $|\langle z,v\rangle|/|v|\leq |z|$. The equality in Cauchy's inequality is attained when the vectors are proportional. So you get the minimum is$|\langle z,v\rangle |/|v|$.

Comment: The typesetting system here interprets '>' and '<' as inequality signs and uses the appropriate spacing for that case. If you want brackets, \langle and \rangle will look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

$$5x+12y=60\implies\;\;(**)\;\; y=-\frac5{12}x+5\implies x^2+y^2=\frac{169}{144}x^2-\frac{50}{12}x+25$$

Since the minimum/maximum of $\,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,$ is the same as $\,x^2+y^2\;$ (why?).

Differentiate the above to get critical points:

$$\frac{169}{72}x-\frac{50}{12}=0\implies x=\frac{300}{169}\stackrel{(**)}\implies y=\frac{720}{169}$$

So the minimal value is

$$\sqrt{\frac{300^2+720^2}{169^2}}=\frac{780}{169}=\frac{60}{13}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the foot of the perpendicular to the line $5x + 12y = 60$ that passes through the origin.  The line has slope $-\frac{5}{12}$, so any perpendicular has slope $\frac{12}{5}$.  The perpendicular passes through the origin, so its equation is $y=\frac{12}{5}x$.  Find the intersection of the two lines:

\begin{aligned}
5x + 12y &= 60\\
y &= \frac{12}{5}x\\
5 x + \frac{12 \cdot 12}{5} x &= 60\\
25x + 144 x &= 300\\
169x &= 300\\
x &= \frac{300}{169}\\
y &= \frac{12}{5} \cdot \frac{300}{169}\\
y &= \frac{720}{169}.
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

One can use the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality, by which $(x^2+y^2)(25+144) \geq (5x+12y)^2$. Therefore, we see that the minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{60^2}{13^2}}$, or $\boxed{\frac{60}{13}}$

Answer (score 0):

I did this with similar triangles:

The constraint is a 5-12-13 right triangle (in Quadrant I), and the objective is simply the Euclidean distance of $(x,y)$ to the origin.

Since we're minimizing the distance from a point (the origin) to a line, it should be clear from the graph we only need to focus on Quadrant I.

Also, to minimize the distance from a point to a line, connect the point to the line with a segment perpendicular to the line.

If you've been drawing, we now have a similar triangle within the 5-12-13 triangle.

[image: illustration]

Our minimum distance is given by:

$\frac{12}{13}=\frac{x}{5}\Rightarrow x=\frac{60}{13}$